# binding to angular component without []

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I am trying to unit test an angular (4) component which contains an angular material based data table. 
I am trying to mock many of the directives e.g. `<md-row cdkColumnDef="title">`, but the `cdkColumnDef` is causing me an issue, because the following does not work:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'md-row',
  template: `<p>Table</p>`
})
class MockContainer {
  @Input() cdkHeaderRowDef;
}
```

with that, I get the error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
        'md-row' is not a known element:
        1. If 'md-row' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'md-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
                  <!-- ID Column -->
                  [ERROR ->]<md-row cdkColumnDef="id">
                    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header> ID </md-header-cell>
                    <md-cell *cdkCellD"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/JobOverviewComponent.html@7:12
```

How do I expose a bindable property that doesn't require square brackets like `@Input()`>

Comment: You can't create component on ng-container. It should be directive `@Directive({selector: '[cdkColumnDef]'})`. Why do not you use material directives?

Comment: `<ng-container>` is a angular `element` you cannot create a component with those selectors which are already defined elements in angular

Comment: @Aravind So should I import it into my test? How to avoid the not recognised issues~?

Comment: `MockContainer` component has `ng-container` as its selector which is wrong. you cannot have this selector

Comment: I am seeing this isse on lots of different selectors, see my updated question

Comment: Looks like you missing some rows

Comment: You must recreate a module with `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` to provide the minimum required for your component to compile. If you need services / pipes, or anything like that. For example you need to import `CdkTableModule`